# Switch focus to a vb.net application on key press

Tags: vb.net, background-process, hotkeys

I have a vb.net application which will be minimized to task bar or notification area. Is there any way for me to maximize/focus on that application when user presses a key (even if the user is using any other application).

Tried windows hot key but doesn't focus the app when it is already open.Please help

Answer (score 1):

You require global hotkeys. First, add these functions to your application.

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyPress Lib "user32" Alias "GetAsyncKeyState" (ByVal key As Integer) As Integer
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindow", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindow(lpClassName As String, lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

Next, add a `Timer` and in its `Timer.Tick` Event, use this function like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If GetKeyPress(Keys.LControlKey) And GetKeyPress(Keys.A) Then
        Dim Handle As IntPtr = Process.GetProcessById(2916).MainWindowHandle
        ShowWindow(Handle, 9)
        SetForegroundWindow(Handle)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Set the `Timer` Interval to 150 to avoid repeated keypresses and make sure to enable the timer in the `Form Load` event.**

Comment: HI Farhan, Thank you. The code worked for the first time. Activated the application from taskbar when i pressed the key combination. But once minimized again, it doesn't work.